# Accessibility Screen reader has different behavior on iPhone X

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, accessibility

I have webView and on LoadFinished method I'm invoking EvaluateJavascript for accessibility mode where it should focus the word or sentence in the web view content. The line of code below, works fine on every iOS device except iPhone X.

`webView.EvaluateJavascript ("javascript: var element = document.getElementsByClassName('highlight'); setTimeout(function(){ element[0].focus(); }, 1500);");`

The flow on iPhone X is: when screen is loaded instead of waiting 1.5 sec and then focus the element, element is focused immediate and then accessibility is focusing the first element of the screen (the button in the nav bar).

Could there be any difference in the accessibility screen reader on the iPhone X and the other iOS devices?

Answer (score 0):

iPhoneX has safeArea which is different from other iPhone.You can open this link for more information.[iPhoneX safeArea](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/overview/iphone-x/)

Comment: Yes, read that, but the problem is focusing on element happens right after loading the screen and then focus goes to first element in nav bar. On other devices this flow is reversed (first is focused the nav bar element then the right element) which is how I want. I this this is not because of the safe area

Comment: Is the version of system same? iOS11 or iOS10

Comment: In my test devices: iPhone 8 is 11.0.3, iPhone X 11.4.1

Comment: You were right the problem is iOS 11.4 bug, I tried on iPhone 6s with iOS 11.4 version and I got the same behavior so this is the bug in the iOS, going feather to resolve the problem